# VS 2019 - Ability to view CS file in Form Designer keeps disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm running VS 2019 Community, version 16.11.5 (recently updated), and I'm a bit unfamiliar with the IDE, admittedly.

I'm seconded to another team for a while to maintain a C# WinForm application (.Net Framework 4.7.2); the rest of the team all have a paid-for professional copy of VS 2019, rather than the community edition. Despite that, I was able to clone the relevant project onto my laptop ten days ago and start work - and I was definitely able to right-click a CS source file and open it in the Form Designer.

After 2 or 3 days, for some reason, I started up VS and was unable to get the View Form right-click menu option to work again. I tried various things (which I cannot entirely remember) and, somehow, the menu option returned. I put it down to a glitch and continued...

...but it has now happened again, and I can't see why I keep hitting this problem.

Here's the Solution Explorer view:

[image]

I've looked at similar reported issues and chief amongst them is to check that I've not added any code BEFORE the declared Form class - but I haven't. Here's the beginning of SelectByAttributesDialog.cs:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class SelectByAttributesDialog : Form
    {
        Sprocs SQL = new Sprocs();
```

... etc ...

and here's the start of SelectByAttributesDialog.Designer.cs:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    partial class SelectByAttributesDialog
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

so it doesn't appear as if that's the problem. In fact there are many more forms files that I haven't edited which have the same issue -- and they all show the C# icon in the Solution Explorer rather than the 'form' icon which my colleagues see in their professional editions for the same code cloned from the same repository.

I've also checked that none of my files are excluded from the project.

I've cleaned the project, rebuilt the project, committed my code to git, restarted VS, all several times - without success. Also tried switching to Folder View and back again to Solution Explorer view.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Is this issue specific to particular project? Have you looked with creating new sample project?

Comment: Have you manually edited the `.designer.cs` file with a text editor?  The Designer _owns_ that file; if you manually change stuff, you can mess up its understanding of the world

Comment: @Flydog57
The Designer.cs has been edited - yes - a few times to edit InitializeComponents(). However, the Form Designer view has still been available after these edits. Not only that, but when I cloned the project that my team had been working on for a long time before I did, they too had edited lots of Designer.cs files without a problem, and still can. The fact is that I can't use Form Designer on ANYTHING, even files that I haven't touched but which my team have no issues with accessing Form Designer.

Comment: Note the lock icon before the designer.cs file, the IDE knows that you can't design.  Editing the file with the text editor and trying to save it might give you a better diagnostic.  Next take a look at the [activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround found ...**

I knew that my designer.cs file wasn't incorrectly formatted but nevertheless tried various things to clean it up - all without success.

I switched around different project views, looked at configuration settings, did some git commits/pushes, VS restarts, laptop reboots, etc., etc. Again, none of these worked.

In the end, I sort of followed the advice of @umesh -- I just added a new form to my project. Straight away, the Solution Explorer changed all the icons of forms-based source code from the 'C#' icon to the 'form' icon, and I was able to right-click a .cs file and see the 'View Form' option again ! I then deleted the dummy form.

It looks like a subtle bug in VS - almost as if it had lost a bit of solution configuration which was "re-installed" when I added the new form.

Hopefully this will help others.